# Understanding the Bloch Sphere Better

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, bloch-sphere

Numerous times I have used the Bloch sphere and visualized gates as rotations. For Z and X rotations, it is a pretty good representation. However, today I found that this does not stand for Y/2 gate. Y/2 on $|0\rangle$ gives $|+\rangle$, which is what I would expect. However, Y/2 on $|0\rangle$ gives $-|-\rangle$ instead of $|-\rangle$. Under what conditions do we need to include an extra factor, possibly $-1$, but could be more complicated, for gates in the Bloch sphere picture?

Answer (score 0):

Let us have a Bloch sphere where $+\hat{x}$, $+\hat{y}$, and $+\hat{z}$ correspond to the states $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+i|1 \rangle )$, and $|0\rangle$ respectively. The X gate, Y gate, and Z gate each correspond to a 180 degree turn about the x, y, and z axes respectively.

A gate sending $|0\rangle$ to $|+\rangle$ and $|1$ to $|-\rangle$ (a Hadamard gate) swaps $+\hat{x}$ and $+\hat{z}$, flipping the direction of $+\hat{y}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I guess my question is more geared towards in what circumstances does executing a gate give you an extra factor in the front? For example, X on |-> gives -|->.